# Will regular slamming of car doors cause damage during the lifetime of the vehicle?

Tags: maintenance, door, damage, wear, testing

How long would door slamming take to affect the regular functioning of the vehicle in any way, and are there any ways to find how many door slams a door for a particular individual make/model can take (e.g. via manufacturer testing reports) before there is damage (to the door or elsewhere)?

#### Background

Vehicles differ in the minimum force required to close their doors. Someone who drives a heavier vehicle may be more prone to assuming the same amount of force required to close a lighter vehicle's door, which could result in accidentally slamming it.

Specific example: a Suzuki Ventura requires a certain amount<sup>1</sup> of force to close its door normally, but when the same amount of force is applied to the door of a lighter Toyota Corolla, it results in a noticeable 'slam'.

Drivers can *ask* passengers to close the door lightly, but that won't always be carried out as hoped.

#### What I know so far

- Some aspects of cars are put through *very* rigorous testing, but I'm not sure if the doors are included in that testing, nor if those test results are publicly available?
- Some googling shows anecdotal stories (from reddit etc). For example:

  - Someone [broke an interior latch](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/28trnr/why_is_slamming_the_car_door_bad/),
  - And someone [caused the window to fall of its tracks](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ycimz/does_slamming_car_doors_cause_damage_and_is_it/).
- It's still very hard to gauge how often this occurs, and these anecdotes could turn out very differently for different make/model.

<sup>1</sup><sub>If this can be measured/quantified, please let me know how that's done and I'll include it</sub>

Comment: When BMW bought Landrover, some Landrover engineers had to go to the German factory to see the new standards to be worked to. At the end of the production line they saw an employee open the door to the X5 and throw in a cat. They asked "what the h*ll is that for?". The reply was "it's top check air tightness - if the cat is dead in 24 hours then the X5 passes. So, back to the Uk production line, opened the door of a Defender and chucked a cat in. 24 hours later they went to check and the cat  had escaped... :) Joke.

Comment: Oh, just btw, a Rolls has one of the heaviest doors and it does not need slamming... Neither does my Jag... But cheaper cars...

Comment: This is really a subjective question ... what does "slamming" a car door mean? How much force is the border line between closing and slamming?

Comment: Rough treatment of any mechanical device (the door contains the locking and the window mechanisms) will shorten its life, or be more likely to cause damage than treating it gently.

Comment: @WeatherVane That makes sense. I guess the question is *how* soon will that have an effect. For example, if doors are made to withstand, say, 100,000 slams, then I think it's almost not worth worrying about (unless the car is used for uber or something like that). But if it could break/be damaged after, say, 100 slams, then that's a different story..